# How to address a Chinese co-worker?

Tags: work-environment, etiquette, greetings, cross-culture

Question similar to  [How to address a Korean co-worker?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/26195/113)

When interacting in direct chat messages in English with co-workers (software developers like me) from Chinese offices ; is it rude to address them with their first name, and how could I greet them in a way both polite and not too distant?

When referring to Chinese co-workers in chat channels shared with other members, is it polite to use their full name, or are there more appropriate wordings?

Answer (score 2):

Chinese is my mother tongue, below is my personal experience and based on different top 10 major cities in China.

Typically to address people is 你好 direct translate to "You Good" or same meaning as Hello.

You can address people "informally" as 靓仔 "beautiful boy" or 靓女 "beautiful girl" that most likely they would like to hear. Try do this for those for less than 50 years else they will feel that you are mocking them. Unless they just look like Keanu Reeves.

Try out to learn from google translate for correct pronunciation else or it might carry different meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the company chat we are communicating in English. Do you think it would be OK to use the English versions of these expressions? Or can I just paste the Chinese words after my English "Hi"?

Comment: Just use pin yin "Ni Hao" instead chinese word 你好 will do, no need Hi. It enough to show basic respect n understanding of the culture